Where are the KSP logs?
I'm trying to get a custom KSP annotation working, and bazel is giving me this error:
error: [ksp] No providers found in processor classpath.
error: error occurred in KSP, check log for detail

Adding --subcommands --verbose_failures adds no useful information.
I am supplying a processor_class to a class that exists in a dependency.
I looked around in bazel-out for a while. Nothing obvious.
Soooo.. Where are the logs?
Related question : If I want to debug using KSP's logging, where do those end up? How can I see them?
=== UPDATE ===
By searching the path from bazel info output_base, I found a file called worker-0-KotlinKsp.log but it has a zero length.
